# PHP - why displaying associative array using foreach is causing line gaps?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my code to display my associative array

```
$i=1;
echo '<pre>';
foreach($bendetails as $bd)
{
    $i=str_pad($i,'2','0',pad_left);
    echo $i.'. '.$bd['cd2'].'<br />';
    echo $i.'. '.$bd['bban'].'<br />';
    $i++;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

when i am using `print_r($bendetails);` it's output is fine

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bban] => Bank Account Number
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        [bban] => Bank Account Number
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
          [bban] => Bank Account Number
        )
)
```

and when I use above mentioned `foreach` to display it, I don't know from where, it is showing the output like

```
01 A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
01 
02 
02 Bank Account Number
03 A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
03 
04 
04 Bank Account Number
05 A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
05 
06 
06 Bank Account Number
```

Can anyone please tell is there anything missing? What is causing these extra spaces. I am new to PHP arrays. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you got is the expected result, having the shown array structure.

Comment: @hek2mgl - but it is showing extra lines, and i didn't want them... if u have downvoted the question, remove the down vote. i already said, i am NEW...

Comment: This has nothing to do with *being NEW*. Just use your eyes. However, @SyamMohan has already the right answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your always printing both values, even if the keys do not exist.
You should check that the key exists before printing:

```
foreach ($bendetails as $bd)
{
    $i=str_pad($i,'2','0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if (array_key_exists('cd2', $bd)){
        echo $i.'. '.$bd['cd2'].'<br />';
    }
    if (array_key_exists('bban', $bd)){
        echo $i.'. '.$bd['bban'].'<br />';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian P.. duration is one minute only??? i have accepted your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Change your array format like this

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        [bban] => Bank Account Number
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        [bban] => Bank Account Number
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [cd2] => A=Add/U=Update/D=Delete
        [bban] => Bank Account Number
    )

)
```

Comment: and how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The correct use of the `str_pad()` function involves using a PHP CONSTANT called `STR_PAD_LEFT` and not just an arbitrary name `pad_left` so the padding command should be

```
$i=str_pad($i, '2', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Maybe this is causing the unexplained odd spacing? Especially as the default padding is STR_PAD_RIGHT which is probably what you are being given.